# How do you use the DrawBorder event in ToolTip Draw method?

Tags: c#, tooltip

Could someone post some examples of how to use the DrawBorder in the ToolTip's Draw event?  I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
e.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, 
             Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
             Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
             Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,  
             Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set the `OwnerDraw` property of the `ToolTip` to `true` to have your custom code actually invoked; second, you can only use a series of standard Windows Forms graphics calls to render your desired graphics elements to `e.Graphics`, since the `DrawTooltipEventArgs.DrawBorder()` call you have attempted takes no parameters and always uses the system border color.